# Having multiple types of sorts for an object

Tags: java

Lets say that I have an java object with multiple String fields.

```
public class Person {
    private String field1
    // keeps going
```

I want to be able to have the ability to sort a list of persons depending on whatever field I choose.

I know that I can use the comparator interface and implement multiple compareTo's as described in the topic: [How do I make 2 comparable methods in only one class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432774/how-do-i-make-2-comparable-methods-in-only-one-class)

But while using `Collections.sort()`

But is there some way for me to do this without all this repeating code?

Comment: Which repeating code?

Comment: I'm not working with Java, but you could try some googling for "orderby for java" referring to the corresponding .NET Linq method.

Comment: Pick all strings into collection and switch index by which comparator will select string from every object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to be able to have the ability to sort a list of persons
>   depending on whatever field I choose.

**@JB Nizet's** solution for **Java 8** will make a trick but it works only from Java 8. What about version(s) lower than 8 which are used by majority of people?

I will provide you i think simple solution for lower versions than Java 8.

You really don't need to create more than one `Comparator` class (you mentioned it as "repeating code"). What about to use proper techniques like if conditions or enums?

```
private Comparator<YourClass> getComparator(MyPropertiesEnum myEnum) {
   return new Comparator<YourClass>() {

      @Override
      public int compare(YourClass o1, YourClass o2) { {
         switch (myEnum) {
            case FIRSTNAME:
               // implementation for firstname
            break;
            case LASTNAME:
              // implementation for lastname
            break;
            default:
               // implementation for default version
            break;           
         }
      }
   };
}
```

Where `MyPropertiesEnum` can looks like:

```
public enum MyPropertiesEnum {
   FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, AGE;
}
```

**Note:** Also you can use proper if conditions if they are more comfortable for you.

Hope it'll help you solve your issue.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't like the verbosity of `Comparator` classes, then use Java 8 and its lambda expressions:

```
Comparator<Person> byName = Comparator.comparing(Person::getName);
Comparator<Person> byBirthDate = Comparator.comparing(Person::getBirthDate);
```

Comment: Thanks, this will be useful for me later on. But I'm not using Java 8 at the moment? Is there no elegant way for me to do this without Functional Programming?

Comment: Define a class (anonymous or not) for each comparator. It's more verbose, but it's not *that* verbose.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Person {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    ...
    private Map<String,String> allFields;

    ...
    public void setField1 (String value) {
        field1 = value;
        allFields.put("field1",value);
    }

    public void setField2 (String value) {
        field2 = value;
        allFields.put("field2",value);
    }
```

Or whatever names you want.  Or you can use an `enum` instead of a `String` as the map key.  This demonstrates why using getters and setters is a good idea, by the way; you couldn't do this by using public member fields and letting clients assign to them directly.  But since you make the fields `private` and require a setter to set them, you can ensure that the `String` field and the map entry always match.

Now it should be easy to write a single `Comparator` that looks for the desired field by looking it up in `allFields`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an sketch of a generic approach.

It should work as long as the types of the fields implement the `compareTo` method (that is, you should use Integer vs int and so on)

**DISCLAIMER**: I have not taken into account any performance issues :)

Sorter.java

```
package sovflow;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Sorter<ObjectType, FieldType extends Comparable<FieldType>> {

    public List<Wrapper<ObjectType, FieldType>> sort(List<ObjectType> list,
            Field field) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        List<Wrapper<ObjectType, FieldType>> _list = new ArrayList<Wrapper<ObjectType, FieldType>>();
        for (ObjectType object : list) {
            Wrapper<ObjectType, FieldType> wrapper = new Wrapper<ObjectType, FieldType>(
                    field, object);
            _list.add(wrapper);
        }
        Collections.sort(_list);
        return _list;
    }

}
```

Wrapper.java

```
package sovflow;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Wrapper<ObjectType, FieldType extends Comparable<FieldType>>
        implements Comparable<Wrapper<ObjectType, FieldType>> {

    Field field;
    ObjectType object;

    public Wrapper(Field field, ObjectType object) {
        this.field = field;
        this.object = object;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // for the field.get. Unavoidable, i'd say :)
    public int compareTo(Wrapper<ObjectType, FieldType> paramT) {
        try {   
            return ((FieldType) field.get(object)).compareTo((FieldType)field.get(paramT.object));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return 0;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(object);

    }

}
```

This is an example of how to use it:

```
package sovflow;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    private static class Person {

        private Integer id;
        private String name;
        public Person(Integer id, String name) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Id = " + id + " name = " + name;
        }       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p = new Person(1, "B");
        Person p2 = new Person(2, "A");
        List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
        list.add(p);
        list.add(p2);
        Sorter<Person, String> sorter = new Sorter<Person, String>();
        try {
            Field declaredField = Person.class.getDeclaredField("name");
            // Just to show the result. The sort method could be modified to
            // not having to deal with the wrapper here..
            List<Wrapper<Person,String>> list2 = sorter.sort(list, declaredField);          
            for (Wrapper<Person, String> wrapper : list2) {
                wrapper.print();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```